Dropdown multi select not maintaining after closing out
 type SortingKey =
    | "Duration"
    | "Favorited Territories"
    | "Favorited Offices"
    | "Requestable"
    | "Non-Requestable"
    | "Non-Full";

  const [sortingStates, setSortingStates] = useState<{
    [key in SortingKey]: boolean;
  }>({
    Duration: false,
    "Favorited Territories": false,
    "Favorited Offices": false,
    Requestable: false,
    "Non-Requestable": false,
    "Non-Full": false,
  });

const topContent = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center gap-4 w-full">
          {/* Dropdown for selecting search criteria */}
          <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTrigger>
              <Button size="sm" variant="flat">
                Search Criteria
              </Button>
            </DropdownTrigger>
            <DropdownMenu aria-label="Search Criteria" closeOnSelect>
              {columns
                .filter(
                  (column) =>
                    column.uid !== "actions" &&
                    column.uid !== "eventDate" &&
                    column.uid !== "eventType" &&
                    column.uid !== "startTime" &&
                    column.uid !== "favorited"
                )
                .map((column) => (
                  <DropdownItem
                    key={column.uid}
                    className="capitalize"
                    onClick={() => {
                      let lowercasedName = column.name.toLowerCase();
                      // Manually map column names to their corresponding values
                      if (lowercasedName === "office") {
                        setSearchCriteria("Office");
                        setFilterCriteria("officeName");
                      } else if (lowercasedName === "location") {
                        setSearchCriteria("Location");
                        setFilterCriteria("location");
                      } else if (lowercasedName === "territories") {
                        setSearchCriteria("Territories");
                        setFilterCriteria("territory");
                      } else if (lowercasedName === "specialty") {
                        setSearchCriteria("Specialties");
                        setFilterCriteria("specialty");
                      } else if (lowercasedName === "providers") {
                        setSearchCriteria("Providers");
                        setFilterCriteria("providers");
                      }

                      setSearchValue(""); // Clear the search input when changing criteria
                    }}
                  >
                    {column.name.toLowerCase()}
                  </DropdownItem>
                ))}
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>

          {/* Search input */}
          <Input
            isClearable
            classNames={{
              base: "w-full sm:max-w-[44%]",
            }}
            placeholder={`Search by ` + searchCriteria}
            size="sm"
            startContent={
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faMagnifyingGlass}
                width="16"
                height="16"
              />
            }
            variant="underlined"
            value={searchValue}
            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
              setSearchValue(e.target.value);
            }}
            classname="larger-text"
          />

          {/* Dropdown for Specialty */}
          <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTrigger>
              <Button size="sm" variant="flat">
                {filterSpecialty}
              </Button>
            </DropdownTrigger>
            <DropdownMenu
              aria-label="Specialty"
              closeOnSelect={true}
              style={{ maxHeight: "400px", overflowY: "auto" }}
            >
              {specialty_columns.map((specialty) => (
                <DropdownItem
                  key={specialty}
                  onClick={() => {
                    const value =
                      specialty === "Unselect Specialty"
                        ? "Select Specialty"
                        : specialty;
                    setFilterSpecialty(value);
                  }}
                >
                  {specialty}
                </DropdownItem>
              ))}
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>

          {/* Dropdown for Type */}
          <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTrigger>
              <Button size="sm" variant="flat">
                {filterType}
              </Button>
            </DropdownTrigger>
            <DropdownMenu aria-label="Type" closeOnSelect={true}>
              {/* Map your types here */}
              {type_columns.map((type) => (
                <DropdownItem
                  key={type}
                  onClick={() => {
                    const value =
                      type === "Unselect Type" ? "Select Type" : type;
                    setFilterType(value);
                  }}
                >
                  {type}
                </DropdownItem>
              ))}
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>

          <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTrigger>
              <Button size="sm" variant="flat">
                Sorting Options
              </Button>
            </DropdownTrigger>
            <DropdownMenu
              aria-label="Sort Criteria"
              closeOnSelect={false}
              selectionMode="multiple"
            >
              {SORTING_COLUMNS.map((column) => (
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => handleSortOptions(column)}>
                  {column}
                </DropdownItem>
              ))}
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>
          <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTrigger className="hidden sm:flex px-6">
              <Button
                endContent={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} />}
                size="sm"
                variant="flat"
              >
                Display Columns
              </Button>
            </DropdownTrigger>
            <DropdownMenu
              disallowEmptySelection
              aria-label="Table Columns"
              closeOnSelect={false}
              selectedKeys={visibleColumns}
              selectionMode="multiple"
              //This is to change the different columns shown, ignore error from typescript
              onSelectionChange={(newVisibleColumns) => {
                console.log(
                  "Attempting to update visible columns to:",
                  newVisibleColumns
                );

                if (newVisibleColumns.size > 0) {
                  setVisibleColumns(newVisibleColumns);
                } else {
                  //Can provide feedback that they need one box selected atleast here.
                }
              }}
            >
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <DropdownItem key={column.uid} className="capitalize">
                  {column.name.toLowerCase()}
                </DropdownItem>
              ))}
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>
        </div>

        <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
          <span className="text-default-400 text-small">
            Total {meetings.length} meetings
          </span>
          <label className="flex items-center text-default-400 text-small">
            Rows per page:
            <select
              className="bg-transparent outline-none text-default-400 text-small"
              onChange={onRowsPerPageChange}
            >
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="45">45</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }, [
    filterSpecialty,
    filterType,
    //setSortingStates,
    searchCriteria,
    searchValue,
    filterCriteria,
    visibleColumns,
    onRowsPerPageChange,
    meetings.length,
  ]);

return (
    <>
      <ProfileDrawer
        isOpen={drawerOpenOffice}
        onClose={() => setDrawerOpenOffice(false)}
        ID={officeModalId ? officeModalId : "null"}
      />
      <ProviderProfileDrawer
        isOpen={drawerOpenProviders}
        onClose={() => setDrawerOpenProviders(false)}
        providerAtEvent={providerInfo} //provider info
      />
      <div></div>
      <Table
        isCompact
        removeWrapper
        aria-label="Meetings table data"
        bottomContent={bottomContent}
        bottomContentPlacement="outside"
        //sortDescriptor={sortDescriptor}
        topContent={topContent}
        topContentPlacement="outside"
        //onSortChange={setSortDescriptor}
      >
        <TableHeader columns={headerColumns}>
          {(column) => (
            <TableColumn
              key={column.uid}
              align="center"
              allowsSorting={column.sortable}
            >
              <span className="larger-text">{column.name}</span>
            </TableColumn>
          )}
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody emptyContent={"No meetings found"} items={items}>
          {(item) => (
            <TableRow key={item.id}>
              {(columnKey) => (
                <TableCell className="larger-text">
                  {renderCell(item, columnKey)}
                </TableCell>
              )}
            </TableRow>
          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </>

Currently my Sorting Options dropdown allows me to select different options and it filters a table full of things by these options. The problem is when I click on some filters, then i close the sorting options list, the filters remain. However, when I open the sorting options list again, the filtered options arent selected.
Basically the check mark that appears near sorting options doesnt stay when I close it.
